# Есть ли смысловая разница между словами "ошеломительный" и "ошеломляющий"?

Tags: семантика

Есть ли смысловая разница между словами ошеломительный и ошеломляющий?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разница есть. "**Ошеломительный**" (прилагательное) относится к свойствам чего-либо, потенциально *способного ошеломить* кого-либо, чаще всего - в смысле "произвести сильное впечатление". Например, так можно сказать о внешне *эффектном* действии спортсмена или артиста, подразумевая, что оно произвело бы впечатление на любого. "**Ошеломляющий**" (причастие) можно отнести как к сугубо личному впечатлению от наблюдаемого со стороны действия, так и в прямом смысле к эффекту однократного воздействия на кого-то, например. об ударе, который кого-то "*ошеломил*" (удар был неожиданным, застал врасплох или физически заставил, напр. боксёра, потерять ориентацию).

**P.S.** Возможны ситуации, когда уместно использование и того, и другого слова, но по значению они могут различаться, причём не всегда заметно для говорящего, например:

> Спектакль имел ошеломляющий (либо ошеломительный) успех.

Строго говоря, первый вариант констатирует факт большого успеха спектакля в конкретной ситуации (время, место, аудитория - как тогда это подействовало); второй вариант при всём том же характеризует и размер успеха, его сравнительную оценку в ряду успешных мероприятий, которые можно себе представить. Но в этом примере различие уловит не всякий, это вопрос разборчивости автора в выборе слов. Журналисты иногда путают по смыслу даже слова "удачный" и "удачливый".

Answer (score 3):

1) В словаре прилагательные  **даны как синонимы.**

ОШЕЛОМИТЕЛЬНЫЙ,  =Ошеломляющий. О-ое известие. О. бросок. О-ая фигура. 
ОШЕЛОМЛЯЮЩИЙ,  Изумляющий, потрясающий, приводящий в замешательство. О-ая новость. О. успех. О-ее впечатление.

2) В реальности "ошеломительный" встречается значительно **реже,** в Нацкорпусе: ошеломительный - 23 примера, ошеломляющий - 93 примера. Скорее всего, если слова воспринимаются как синонимы, то одно из них теряет частотность употребления.

3) Но **различие в семантике всё же существует**.

**Ошеломительный (прил.)** определяет  качество, **способное** произвести сильное впечатление. Оно постоянное, не зависит от времени и не связано со временем: Странный резкий запах идет от него ― смолистый, густой, веселый, **ошеломительный** запах-дурман. **Ошеломительный** рост преступности был не единственной проблемой, занимавшей правителей.

**Ошеломляющий -** **по происхождению причастие**, поэтому временной фактор в этом случае важен: И тут она понесла такой немыслимый и **ошеломляющий** вздор, что Глебов онемел от изумления. Именно в 95-м году случился тот **ошеломляющий** скандал ― когда госсобственность на огромные суммы была заложена коммерческим банкам.

4) **Сравним различные ситуации** при выборе   ошеломляющий/ошеломительный  успех/эффект.

а) Звезды богемы и бюрократии давились в проходах. Успех **ошеломляющий**. Добавить почти ничего не могу. Концерт **ошеломляющий**. Зал был полон. Резонанс был огромный, поток писем **ошеломляющий**. Эффект был **ошеломляющий**!

В этих примерах для выражения реальных эмоций в конкретный момент лучше использовать прилагательное "ошеломляющий".

б) Никому не ведомый, мальчишка, двадцать пять лет, едва выскочил на страницы журнала, даже книги нет и не член Союза ― и вдруг лауреат! Факт **ошеломительный**, невыносимый.  Ты сам сказал: твоя книга имеет **ошеломительный** успех.

Здесь возможны оба варианта.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд говорить о **смысловой** разнице тут не совсем коррентно. Чтобы указать на смысловую (точнее - семантическую) разницу между причастием и парным нему отглагольным прилагательным надо указать фразу, где можно использовать альтернативно обе формы - и только на этом основании говорить о какой-то семантической разнице. Я такой дифференцирующей фразы построить не могу (как и в большинстве случаев такое пары прилагательного-причастия). 
Все остальные методы и разговоры - малоубедительны.

Ну вот пример, тут разбиравшийся.
*Боксер нанес ошеломляющий удар.

Боксер нанес ошеломительный удар.*
Простите, я не вижу под микроскопом реальной разницы **в значениях**. Разве что стилистическую.

В таких случаях остается говорить только о разнице в грамматическом употреблении. Но это обычные разговоры про зависимые слова - и прочее. Очень редко удается реально вычленить понятийную разницу между обозначением качества и состояния. Наш случай к таковым, видимо не относится.

Кстати, даже эта, всё еще ставящаяся во главу угла академическими грамматиками "качественно-состоятетельная" разница, видимо, тоже стирается. На это первым обратив внимание, кажется, Аванесов - не позже начала 80-х, о чем и написал в комментариях к своему словарю.

(+)
Другое дело, что прилагательное вообще говоря применяется шире причастия. 
Скажем, "у этих духов ошеломляющий запах" выглядит как-то странновато, естественным будет употребить "ошеломительный". Т. е. чем дальше значение от исходного ("приводящий в состояние контузии"), чем в больше в нем переносного, тем естественнее смотрится "ошеломительный". И тут можно признать, что это связано именно с различием значений "качества" и "состояния"